Perl how to read a line from a file with interpolation of embedded new line char
I am trying to print a line from a file with interpolation.
I have the following code:
open FH, "<", "file.txt";
my $line = <FH>;
print "line = " . $line . "\n";

The file.txt contains one line:
one\ntwo

The line prints as "one\ntwo". The \n is not interpolated.
I have tried opening the file with :raw  :crlf  :any
but nothing works.
I have tried using $'one\ntwo' in file.txt as well as all forms of quoting.
I know the following code works:
my $st = "one\ntwo";
print "line = " . $st . "\n";

It prints:
one
two

How do I do that when reading the line from a file?

Why do you expect a backslash and an n to represent anytthing else than that literal character sequence? Use s/\\n/\n/g if that's what you need.

$'one\ntwo' is specifically Bash syntax, but there is no shell involved when you read characters from a file.

You don't even have "one\ntwo", which is Perl code. $'one\ntwo' is bash code. You are not evaluating code; you are reading from a file.
